# CodeMirror - what is addWidget for and how to use it?

Tags: widget, codemirror

I want to make some extensions to CodeMirror.  The addWidget method seems like a promising starting point. The documentation states

> addWidget(pos, node, scrollIntoView) Puts node, which should be an
>   absolutely positioned DOM node, into the editor, positioned right
>   below the given {line, ch} position. When scrollIntoView is true, the
>   editor will ensure that the entire node is visible (if possible). To
>   remove the widget again, simply use DOM methods (move it somewhere
>   else, or call removeChild on its parent).

I don't really understand what that means or what I would use it for.  I cannot find a usage of it in the CodeMirror codebase nor anywhere else in google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an html node and a position and a Boolean value

```
// create a node
var htmlNode =document.createElement("h1");
var text =  document.createTextNode("Text or whatever");
htmlNode.appendChild(text)

// call this after you initialized the editor.
// the position must be like this {ch: YourCharecterNumber, line: YourLineNumber}
editor.addWidget({ch:30 , line: 1},htmlNode, true)
```

Comment: Right, I understand the method signature, what I'm not sure of is what I would use this for. What does it do? What is a use case?

Comment: I used it to add a custom autoComplete widget.

Comment: So you use it to add more DOM elements at a particular locationin the editor? How did this work for your autoComplete? Wouldn't you have to add a widget whever the cursor currently is (I'm assuming it was the familiar way of doing autocmplete via pop-up)?

Comment: It worked well. The widget is added to CM if certain keys are pressed. then I set the focus on the autocomplete input form. I used editor.getCursor() to get the position of the cursor. The autoComlete node is removed on the Return Key Press.I used jQuery Autocomplete.